# Fourier Transform of 1/x

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I am trying to calculate the Fourier Transform of $h(x)=1/x$

So I was thinking:

Since the FT of $g(x)=sign(x)$ is $G(f)=1/(i\pi f)$ ,

then using property of duality gives that $G(x)=1/(i\pi x)$ transforms to $g(-f)=-sign(f)$

Next I used scaling property, and it turns out that -going this way- $h(x)=1/x$ transforms to $H(f)=-\pi sign(i\pi f)=-i\pi^2 sign(f)$, which is different from MATLAB output $-i\pi sign(f)$

I've set MATLAB to be consistent with this definition:

$$F\{f(x)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)exp(-i2\pi fx)dx}$$

Here I am using f as frequency $f=\omega/(2\pi)$ ,
and the properties used are shown [here](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/transform/properties.php)..

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance.-

Comment: Hi, $1/(2i\pi f)$ is the transform of the $0$ mean integrator : of $sign(x) / 2$, thus $-1/(i\pi x)$ transforms to $sign(f)$,  $1/x$ transforms to $- i \pi sign(f)$ (I hate constants me too)

Comment: is it that $sign(\pi f)\neq \pi sign(f)$? the sign cannot be $\pm \pi$.

Comment: @user1952009 it is now clear, using linearity is definitely the right way.. thank you!